# Topological sort for directed graph made of two-dimensional vestor using DFS

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, topological-sort

Here's how I create directed graph in int_main:

```
int edges, vertices;

    cout << "Number of edges" << endl;
    cin >> edges;

    cout << "Number of verticles" << endl;
    cin >> vertices;

    vector<vector<int>> graph(vertices); 

    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < edges; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b; 
        graph[a].push_back(b);
    }
```

My task is to make topological sort for directed graph using DFS.
Here is how I'm trying to implement DFS and topological sort:

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graph, vector<bool> &used, int nodeIndex) {
    used[nodeIndex] = true;
    for (auto i : graph[nodeIndex]) {
        if (!used[i])
            dfs(graph, used, i);
    }
}

void topologicalSort(vector<vector<int>> &graph, vector<bool> &used, int nodeIndex) {
    vector<int> answer;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
        used[nodeIndex] = false;
    answer.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); ++i)
        if (!used[i])
            dfs(graph, used, i);
    reverse(answer.begin(), answer.end());
}
```

But topological sort doesn't seem to work and I can't understand what should I do to fix this.

Comment: when is the answer vector gets filled?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a good problem description. Please [edit] your question to add the expected behavior, the exact error that you get, and all information necessary to reproduce the problem which includes a full program and its inputs.

Comment: Kindly tick the answer if it helped.

Comment: **"**_DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]_**"**

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass answer in the arguments and `push_back(nodeIndex)` in last:

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graph, vector<bool> &used, int nodeIndex, vector<int> &answer) {
    used[nodeIndex] = true;
    for (auto i : graph[nodeIndex]) {
        if (!used[i])
            dfs(graph, used, i);
    }
    answer.push_back(nodeIndex);
}
```

Comment: As I understood I also need to change ```dfs(graph, used, i)``` to ```dfs(graph, used, i, answer)```. But now I'm confused how do I print the sorting result in int_main(). 
I have this function for printing graph:
```
void printGraph(vector<vector<int>> &graph, int vertices) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        cout << i << " : ";
        for (int j : graph[i])
            cout << j << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: for printing topological order, you just need to print the answer vector.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it how to I initialize it in int_main since it's inside the function

Comment: you can change the return type of topological sort function to return the answer vector.

Comment: how do I change it to return vector

Comment: change return type of topological sort from `void` to `vector<int>` and add `return answer` in the last line. In main, just catch it and show.